# Actor Timers - Register timer arguments - Why Func<object, Task> and not Func<Task>

Tags: c#, .net, azure, timer, azure-service-fabric

The signature to register a timer in an actor is:

```
IActorTimer RegisterTimer(Func<object, Task> asyncCallback, object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period);
```

*Question:*

Why does the asynCallback expects to receive the state as a function argument of type object. After all, my callback is already part of the Actor and can access the state directly. Hence, the requirement for the object as a parameter seems redundant.

*Current thoughts*

A possible reason is that this allows us to provide the actors state to a callback that is not part of the actor (is this even possible). Is this the only reason? Or should I have additional considerations when handling state from a timer activated method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I have seen (I haven't used ActorTimers that much myself), it's not the actual actor state that's usually passed (since you have that already available), but the argument to the function you're calling.

One example would be this Actor: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-iot/blob/master/src/actors/StorageActor/StorageActor.cs

Here they pass 'false' as the 'state' to this.SaveToStorage when registering the timer, but later (in OnDeactivateAsync), they call the same this.SaveToStorage with true.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's just so you can define a Timer callback method with a parameter and pass a value in for the parameter when you register the Timer. Then you can call the Timer callback method from somewhere else with a different parameter value. The example posted in this response demonstrates this idea.

Comment: @VaclavTurecek is it maybe confusing that the parameter is called 'state' and not 'args' or something along those lines ?

Comment: Echo the previous comment. Good feedback for @VaclavTurecek and the Service Fabric team ;)